# Python - remove duplicate item from list of dictionaries based on dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that has some duplicate IDs in and I would like to keep the dictionaries that have a value under rsrp and remove the ones that have 0, but if there is a duplicate that has rsrp of 0 in twice I need to keep it.

The current and desired list examples are below, is there a simple way to do this? finding non '0' with a loop is the easy bit but if matching ids are '0' im not sure

```
current_list = [
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0},
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'}
]

desired_list = [
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'}
]
```

Comment: is it assured that for values with `rssi:0` twice, we won't also have a non zero rssi with the same id? Also, is it assured one id will only have atmost 1 non zero rssi? Essentially, any cases where the logic can fail?

Comment: there could be an ID without any none zero values, I haven't seen it yet but there could also be three zeros and one with an value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) there is a method called `unique_everseen`:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

you could use that to get your desired list:

```
desired_list = list(unique_everseen(current_list, key=lambda x: x["rssi"]))
# [{'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0}, {'id': 255, 'rssi': '0'}, 
#  {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0}, {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0}]
```

all that is left to do is select `'rssi'` using the `key` parameter of `unique_everseen`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple iteration .

**Ex:**

```
current_list = [
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0},
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'}
]
seen = set()
result = []
for i in sorted(current_list, key=lambda x: True if x["rssi"] == "0" else False):
    if (i["id"] not in seen and i["rssi"] != "0") or \
            (i["id"] not in seen and i["rssi"] == "0"):
        result.append(i)
        seen.add(i["id"])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0},
 {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0},
 {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0},
 {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'}]
```

Comment: This is assuming that duplicate ids comes sequentially. rssi != 0 always before rssi = 0.
What if they are in reverse order?
`
current_list = [
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0}]
`

This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @MilesDavis. Thank you did not see that case. Updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

If you can use external libraries in your project, you can take advantage of Pandas vectorized operations.

E.g. :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(current_list)
df["rssi"] = pd.to_numeric(df["rssi"])
df = df[(df["rssi"] != 0) | (df.groupby("id").transform("min") == 0)["rssi"]]
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_dict("records")
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `itertools.groupby`. If there's item with `rssi` only `0`, we keep one. We add all other non-zero `rssi` items to output list:

```
current_list = [
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0},
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'}
]

from itertools import groupby

out = []
for v, g in groupby(sorted(current_list, key=lambda k: (k['id'], k['rssi'] == '0')), lambda k: k['id']):
    out.append(next(g)) # ensure we add at least one `0`
    out.extend(i for i in g if i['rssi'] != '0')  # add any non-zero `rssi` items


from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'},
 {'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0},
 {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0},
 {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any `import`s, I would do it following way:

```
current_list = [
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0},
    {'id': 255, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0},
    {'id': 301, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0},
    {'id': 263, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'},
    {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'}
]
output = {}
for i in current_list:
    if not i['id'] in output:
        output[i['id']] = []
    output[i['id']].append(i['rssi'])
# now output is {255: [-108.0, '0'], 301: [-82.0, '0'], 263: [-85.0, '0'], 18: ['0', '0']}
def func(x):
    for j in x:
        if j!='0':
            return j
    return '0'
desired_list = [{'id':i[0],'rssi':func(i[1])} for i in output.items()]
print(desired_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 255, 'rssi': -108.0}, {'id': 301, 'rssi': -82.0}, {'id': 263, 'rssi': -85.0}, {'id': 18, 'rssi': '0'}]
```